# Fixing UI compatible for All type of screen in Single Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image: header placement]

I want to make header placed adjacent to its background. I need to make the view compatible to all the screens without using fixed pixel value.

Help me to Solve this issue.

Comment: You are referring to the grey element with the text "Save $150"?  What about in relative layout with alignLeft?

Comment: how you used? where you used? any xml details pls.. give some proper question

Comment: Please have a look on this **http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/26/android-design-tips/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your screen in two parts by giving weight.
How..?

This is the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffff00"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/baselayout"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"></LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

There you will notice one layout which is of yellow color can act as header in your code. It will act same for all device. you can increase and decrease the weight of layout as your requirment, as how the header you want.